# Equality of integrals of periodic functions for general measure space

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

We know that given a $T$-periodic function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$,

$$\int_{[s_0,s_0+T]}f(x)dx=\int_{[s_1,s_1+T]}f(x)dx$$

for any $s_0$ and $s_1$. This can be proved easily by change of variable. It is also true if the domain is 'splitted' properly. For example,

$$\int_{[s_0,s_0+T]}f(x)dx=\int_{[s_0,t_0]\cup[t_0+T,s_0+2T]}f(x)dx$$

where $s_0<t_0<s_0+T$. For this specific and simple domain, it can be proved easily as well by **shifting by $T$** the domain pieces on the right-hand side and **merging** the pieces into a whole one same as that on the left-hand side. We can conclude informally that the integrals are equal if one domain can be transformed by shifting and merging to the other one.

My question, for a general measure space $(X, \mu)$ and $T$-periodic function $f(x)$, is there any similar conditions on the domains $\Omega_0$ and $\Omega_1$ such that

$$\int_{\Omega_0}f(x)dx=\int_{\Omega_1}f(x)dx.$$

My conjecture is that **one condition is $\mu(\Omega_0)=\mu(\Omega_1)$** so that the new merged domain from one is of the same size as the other one. This is of course not sufficient. We need to characterize the shifting property which I have no idea about.

Comment: First of all, you need some notion of 'addition' on $X$. And then, you can similar cut $\Omega_0$, shift pieces around (by multiples of $T$) and merge them to get $\Omega_1$.

Comment: @gerw Intuitively it seems OK If for example we assume it is lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and 'addition' is defined as usual. My concern is whether the integral is preserved if the domain is broken into very **tiny pieces**, e.g., points and scattered very broad. In other words, can the measure be preserved with respect to shift ?

Comment: @gerw I guess the other missing condition is the measure should preserve with respect to shift . In summary, if the measure is preserved with respect to shift and the two domains have the same measure, then the integrals must be equal. How do you think about it ?

Comment: Yes, this sounds fine. And for a $\sigma$-additive measure you can take countably many pieces - but not more ;)